# Exiting a tree of recursive calls when a solution is found

Tags: python, algorithm

I have this problem, given a set of numbers S and a number N find some combination of numbers S that sum to N such that the solution uses the minimal amount of numbers. ie minimize |Solution|

So for example say S = {1000, 500, 250, 100}, and A = 900 then Solution = {500, 100, 100, 100, 100}

This was my attempt

```
numbers = [1000, 500, 250, 100]
amount = 900

def solve(numbers, amount, sum, solution):
    for num in numbers:
        if sum + num <= amount:
            if sum + num == amount:
                print(solution + [num])
                return
            solve(numbers, amount, sum + num, solution + [num])

solve(numbers, amount, 0, [])
```

And it works! Sort of, I get the right answer and its always the first value I print (Since I ensure the set of numbers is in decreasing order). But the algorithm goes on to print every other correct answer (correct here meaning in sum not minimizing the |Solution|)

> [500, 100, 100, 100, 100] [250, 250, 100, 100, 100, 100] [250, 100,
>   250, 100, 100, 100] [250, 100, 100, 250, 100, 100] [250, 100, 100,
>   100, 250, 100] [250, 100, 100, 100, 100, 250]

and so on

How could I exit this algorithm when I find the first answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not using the return value:

```
numbers = [1000, 500, 250, 100]
amount = 900
def solve(numbers, amount, sum, solution):
    for num in numbers:
        if sum + num <= amount:
            if sum + num == amount:
                print(solution + [num])
                return True
            if solve(numbers, amount, sum + num, solution + [num]):
                return True
     return False

solve(numbers, amount, 0, [])
```